# Does Azure Python SDK Supports Billing API?

Tags: python, azure, billing

I am new to Azure, and I want to use their billing API (especially Azure Resource Usage). And I hope I can use python to better support the whole project.

Thus, the sample code of Billing API is written in C#, which is not really helpful for me.

I have researched into the Azure Python SDK (http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for the whole day, but I did not find the class related to the billing API.

I am wondering whether I can find a Python library to call Billing API and help me monitor the usage of the Azure VM?

Appreciate for the help!

Comment: I have also been unable to find anything within python but you could translate the C# into python. Or you could ask on [Azure-for-python's issues](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues) to see if they actually do support it, or could in the future.

Comment: Thanks Cory, I have asked on github, and been informed that they will launch a new package by this week.

Comment: No problem glad to hear.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Billing APIs haven't been implemented into Azure SDK for Python currently.

However, there is the similar requirement with you asked at the GitHub repository of Azure SDK for Python, refer to [issue #600](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/600). And the MS engineer has answered the issue about the plan of the Azure Python SDK for Billing APIs.

You can monitor the issue thread on GitHub for any update of the SDK.

Comment: Yes, that one is ask by myself, and now they already publish the preview package~ Nice Azure team!